# Why do I see double asterisk at the end of links created by grails g:link tag?

Tags: grails

The code like this:

```
<g:link controller="category" action="show" id="${category.id}">${category.name}</g:link>
```

produces the next link:

```
<a href="/shop/categories/show/1/**">Test category</a>
```

Why does it happen and how to remove this bad-looking double asterisk?

Comment: What do you have in your `URLMappings`?  And what version of Grails?

Comment: @IanRoberts: it looks that you're right and it takes the double asterisks from URLMappings. Grails 2.0.4, URLMappings contains this `"/categories/$action?/$id?/**?"`. But I really want to tell grails that I don't care if URL contains some unnecessary parts after the meaningful part.

Comment: @Roman: You should care.  URLs are meaningful in today's semantic web.  Invalid URLs should be treated as such.

Comment: @Gregg: but, for some reason, it's said in grails docs that grails supports `**` as a wildcard in URLs. But at the same time `g:link` generates ugly links. Either I apply the described technique in a wrong way or it's a bug in `g:link` implementation.

Comment: Try it without the `?`, i.e. `.../$id/**`

Comment: @IanRoberts: now the link ends with `/categories/show/1/**`

Comment: Or bind it to a dummy parameter, `.../$id?/$path**?`.

Comment: @IanRoberts: this way it works as it should, thanks!

Comment: Glad you've got it working, I've expanded my research into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment:

> URLMappings contains this `"/categories/$action?/$id?/**?"`. But I really want to tell grails that I don't care if URL contains some unnecessary parts after the meaningful part.

Unbound wildcards (`*` and `**`) do the right thing for "forward" URL mappings (i.e. taking an incoming request URI and mapping it to a controller action with parameters) but, looking at the source code for the default `RegexUrlMapping`, if you try to use such a mapping in reverse the `*` and `**` components will be included literally in the generated URL.  In order to be able to generate sensible URLs every segment of the mapping must be either a literal or bound to a named variable, so the generator can know what (possibly empty) value it should use to replace the wildcard.

If you were to use the mapping

```
"/categories/$action?/$id?/$path**?"
```

then it would still match the same URIs in forward mode (storing the trailing portion of the URI after the `id` in `params.path`) but `<g:link controller="category" action="show" id="${category.id}">` will know to use an empty trailing component because you didn't specify `params="[path:'something']"`.