# Spring Security CAS Plugin and Not Redirecting to denied Action

Tags: grails

I wrote a functional test using Geb to perform an access denied scenario. The problem is that for some reason the `LoginController.denied` isn't called. Instead I'm going to the success controller, but throws errors in the GSP since there are conditional tags.

If I analyze the test it appears the JSESSIONID param is appended to the URL like so: `https://<host>/;JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXX`

If I remove the JSESSIONID param at a break point it works as normal.

Is this a problem with UrlMapping or a problem with the plugin? I can't seem to figure out the problem.

**UPDATE**
I think its my UrlMapping `"/"(action: 'index', controller: 'dashboard')`
I changed it to `"/**"(action: 'index', controller: 'dashboard')` and the ;XXXX is no longer an issue, but I need to regress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was definitely the URL mapping, but `"/**` caused some unwanted URL links.

Took the advise of [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162204/why-do-i-see-double-asterisk-at-the-end-of-links-created-by-grails-glink-tag/13175762#13175762) and used:

```
"/$path**"(action: 'index', controller: 'dashboard')
```